# Count() return total instead distinct count

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have qualified risks with description and creation date, who are attached to subcategory of risks this last ones are attached to category of risks, each risk has a name like 'Risk_1' , my aim is to count the number of risks by month and risk category including zero.

I have this request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT risk_names.type as risk_name, MONTH(risk.creation_date) as month, count(risk.id) as number FROM risk As risk , risk_category
   JOIN  (
    SELECT risk_category.name as type
    FROM
      risk_category
    ) as risk_names on risk_names.type = risk_category.name
where risk.creation_date >= (NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH) GROUP BY MONTH(risk.creation_date), risk_names.type;
```

Who return this result :

```
Risk_name          month  number
---------------------------------
Risk_1              1      10   ---> instead 8
Risk_2              1      10   ---> instead 1
Risk_3              1      10   ---> instead 1
Risk_1              2      12  ......
Risk_2              2      12
Risk_3              2      12
Risk_1              12     4
Risk_2              12     4
Risk_3              12     4
```

As you can see the number returned is the total for each month , but my aim is to get total for each distinct risk.
Can you help me . thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The query has many errors.

Answer (score 1):

The comma in your `FROM` is doing a `CROSS JOIN`.  A Cartesian product is unnecessary and throws all the counts off.

I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT rc.type as risk_name, MONTH(r.creation_date) as month,
       count(r.id) as number
FROM risk_category rc LEFT JOIN
     risk r
     ON r.?? = rc.??
where risk.creation_date >= (NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
GROUP BY rc.type, MONTH(r.creation_date);
```

I don't know what the `JOIN` criterion is between `risk` and `risk_category`.

Comment: thank you for your answer , Initially I have the same request as yours but this last one doesn't work, because I need the count for all risk_category even those who doesn't exist in risk regarding to a month

Comment: @MK-rou . . . You simply need an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Then try using `distinct` keuword with `count()` like `count(distinct risk.id) as number` instead